# What is $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} p^{-n}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

What is $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} p^{-n}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

I'm thinking it should be infinity or undefined as its $\frac{1}{0}$ or looking another way, it's an infinite distance from $0$ by $\lvert \cdot\rvert_p$.

But I have a hint of doubt because it's $0.000..._p=0$

Comment: A sequence $a_n$ converges in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ iff it is Cauchy for $|.|_p$ iff the sequence $\sup_{m \ge n} |a_n-a_m|_p$ converges to $0$.

Comment: In $\mathbb Q_p$, you actually have the easier condition $\left|a_{n+1}-a_n\right|_p\to 0$. @reuns

Comment: @ThomasAndrews am I right in thinking this depends on $\lvert\cdot\rvert_p\in\mathbb{Z}$? But if we were to define $\lvert\cdot\rvert_p\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ we would have the opposite answer. Is there some good reason why this must not be done?

Comment: Actually, $|\cdot|_p\in\mathbb Q$. And metrics are always going to $\mathbb R$. If we define $a_n\to 0$ in $\mathbb Q_p$ to mean $|a_n|_p\to 0$ in $\mathbb Q_p$, we have a circular definition. @RobertFrost

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, $|p^{-n}|_p=p^n$ so the sequence is clearly unbounded in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and has no limit.

Saying the limit is $0.000\cdots_p\,$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is like saying $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}10^n\,$ is $\cdots0000\,$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But here's my doubt.  You say "it goes to $p^n$" but that in turn is $0$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ so although it goes to infinity, the infinity it goes to is equal to zero.  So I guess the question boils down to; is $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or $\mathbb{Z}$. Is there any impediment to us defining $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2\in\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: @RobertFrost Nowhere in my answer did I use the phrase "it goes to $p^n$." It is just plum wrong to say "the infinity it goes to is equal to zero." That's nonsense. Absolute values are real numbers, they measure distance from $0$ in the space. In particular, $|x|_p$ is rational. For the purposes of measuring distance in $\Bbb Q_p$, that means $|x|_p$ is a real number, but there are other situations where we would also treat $|x|_p$ as an element of $\Bbb Q_p$ (which also contains the rationals), for instance the product formula $\prod_{p\le\infty} |x|_p=1$, which holds for rational $x$.

Comment: I can see merit in defining $\lvert\cdot\rvert_p\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ because it's analogous to the real projective line. It's equating $2^{+\infty}$ with $2^{-\infty}$ in the metric, which then gives us some natural relation between the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ and a circle.

Comment: Can't say I understand your comment.

Comment: If $\lvert\cdot\rvert_p\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ then when the metric goes to $\lim_{n\to\infty}p^n$ it is not, as you say, unbounded, it too $=0$ and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty} p^{-n}=0$.  So $\pm\infty$ are superimposed as in the real projective line.

Comment: You are mixing up convergence in two different metric spaces. The sequence $p^{-n}$ diverges in $\Bbb Q_p$ because the corresponding sequence of absolute values $p^n$ diverges in $\Bbb R$. Your analogy to the real projective line seems like nonsense.

Comment: But ask yourself what do those same absolute values $p^n$ go to if they too are in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and not in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yeah, $||p^{-n}|_p|_p=|p^n|_p=p^{-n}$. Whoop-de-do.

Comment: Neither, the symbol $\infty$ does not refer to any element of $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q_p$, and the equation $p^n=p^{-n}$ is not true because it is missing the $p$-adic absolute value bars. (Except when $n=0$.)

Comment: Sorry are you saying "$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert p^{n}\rvert_p=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert p^{-n}\rvert_p=0$ whoop-de-doo" or "$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert p^{n}\rvert_p\neq\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert p^{-n}\rvert_p$ whoop-de-doo"?

Comment: With the understanding that absolute values are real numbers, your first equation is false and your second inequality is true. My whoop-de-do is saying that just because high powers of $p$ are big in $\Bbb R$ and small in $\Bbb Q_p$ doesn't mean $\Bbb Q$ "wraps around" as the extended number line does because two different metrics are being used, you might as well think of $\Bbb Q_p$ and $\Bbb R$ as distinct sets.

Comment: The proposition is to drop the understanding that absolute values are real numbers, i.e. define $\lvert\cdot\rvert_p:\mathbb{Q}_p\to\mathbb{Q}_p$ instead of $\lvert\cdot\rvert_p:\mathbb{Q}_p\to\mathbb{R}$ and then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert p^{n}\rvert_p=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert p^{-n}\rvert_p=0$ but it was just a comment; no biggy

Comment: In order to interpret a limit, you have to have an understanding of which metric the limit is being taken with respect to. When we write $\lim p^n=0$, we are taking the limit in $\Bbb Q_p$. When we write $\lim |p^n|_p=0$, we are taking the limit of $|p^n|_p$ within $\Bbb R$. When *you* write $\lim |p^n|_p=0$, you're taking the limit of $|p^n|_p$ in $\Bbb Q_p$. You are not treating $|\cdot|_p$ as $\Bbb Q_p$-valued "instead" of $\Bbb R$-valued, you are using both interpretations simultaneously.

Comment: It would seem you are saying to use $\mathbb{R}$ is inescapable whereas I imagine we can just define the limit to $\pm\infty$ as zero without impediment and all will be fine.

Comment: If you're in the mood to define words that already have meaning to have any other meaning you want, then you could define the limit to be fish.

Comment: I would have to have a motivation to so so, and I have no reason to define the limit to be fish.